# I cannot connect to the ssh console on my VM instance on Google Cloud Platform

Tags: ssh, debian, virtual-machines, google-cloud-platform, console

I am currently having problem connecting to the ssh console of my vm instance. If you need info on the vm instance I think the operating system is a Linux Debian 3.7.4. I think it has something to do with the SSH keys on the instance. The Opencart website hosted on the instance still works. Here is a screenshot of the error message which is (#15):[Screenshot of error(#15)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YNaPI.png)

Also, here is some of info from the stackdriver log:

[Screenshot of Stackdriver log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6PxJd.png)

Comment: Same error, i literally just installed a lamp stack on ubuntu 18.04 and now i cant ssh using putty or even the google ssh thing. any help is great!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solved the problem of why I couldn't login to the SSH console. For some reason I had the Block project wide SSH keys checked in my vm instance's details. Now I still have to upload a new ssl certificate for the opencart site. If you guys need me to post this into a different topic I will.